# Assembly references assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.types, version=14.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, clr

I have a problem that I can't figure out. I'm attempting to load a CLR into SQL Server 2016 but I'm getting the error

> Assembly 'xxx' references assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.types, version=14.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91.', which is not present in the current database.

I understand what the error means but it feels like I've hit a dead end resolving the problen. A few things to note:

1. In SQL Server, I have microsoft.sqlserver.types v13, but I can't drop or alter it as it's system.[image]
2. I cannot add microsoft.sqlserver.types v14 because of point 1.
3. In my Visual Studio project, there are no references to microsoft.sqlserver.types v14 anywhere.
4. I've tried installing/reinstalling through nuget.
5. I cannot downgrade to microsoft.sqlserver.types v13 in my project as it says my reporting dependencies will not work, and I need those to work.[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: There are conflicting things here. You say you have no references to version 14 but then state you *have* to use 14 due to other dependances; this contradicts the other.

Comment: Just to clarify, I did have references to v14 (add via nuget, then reinstalled, then removed). I manually added the v13 assembly in the project, then checked the project for v14 references and couldn't find any :)

Comment: Step back.  Why are you trying to load Microsoft.ReportingService.ReportViewerControl.WebForms in a SQLCLR method?  The available reference assemblies in SQLCLR are very limited.

Comment: I'm trying to create a CLR that will execute, then export a SSRS report

Comment: I doubt you'll succeed.  Just do it from a Powershell Agent job, or an SSIS package.  Either one can be invoked from a stored procedure. Or just use SSRS URL Access to render the report in whatever format you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16